# Scale only non zero elements in Vector

Tags: r, normalization

I have a sparse vector/column in data table that I am using as a feature which has mostly zero's and then a few non zero elements. I wanted to scale/normalize the vector, but only for the non zero entries.

Any thoughts how to efficiently implement this.

Thanks in advance

```
c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,20,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,3,1,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
```

returns 0's and then I guess the abosolute value of the scaled numbers

Answer (score 3):

We create a logical index ('i1') and `scale` the vector based on it.

```
i1 <- v1!=0
v1[i1] <- scale(v1[i1])
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,20,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,3,1,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
```